# CGContextRef => CGImageRef => CIImage => CGImageRef => CGContextDrawImage chain turns image upside down

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, core-image

This issue kills me. I do not know what is going wrong. But the following code turns the image upside down. It does a vertical flip in fact and I do not know why.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];

NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kStrokeWidth] forKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
[attributes setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
[attributes setObject:style forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];

[text drawInRect:drawRect withAttributes:attributes];

[attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
[attributes removeObjectForKey:NSStrokeColorAttributeName];
[attributes setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[text drawInRect:drawRect withAttributes:attributes];

CGImageRef cgImg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];

CIContext *cicontext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef cgimg = [cicontext createCGImage:beginImage fromRect:[beginImage extent]];
CGContextDrawImage(context, [beginImage extent] , cgimg);
CGImageRelease(cgImg);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);


UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

This will result in this:

[image]

Why, oh why?

Comment: Probably you lose the rotation when you create the context, where that method is called?and why are you creating also a CIContext

Comment: I create the CIContet to render the CIImage back to CGImageRef. What rotation are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *might* be more appropriate as a comment than as an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

As @Andrea noted, it's a little weird that you are creating both a CGContext and CIContext.  If you just want to extract a UIImage from a CGImageRef you can use

```
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImg]
```

The resulting `newImage` will *still* be flipped.  The coordinate systems used by UIImages and CGContextRefs have oppositely oriented vertical axes.  I recommend that you flip your initial CGContextRef vertically while drawing:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, CGBitmapContextGetHeight(context));
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
// All your drawing code goes here.
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: This is a good explanation thank you. I was not aware of this coordinate issue. That can explain the problem. Yet I am a bit confused why it is not happening both ways (render to and from CIImage should do the flip twice) The reason to convert the image to CIImage is to apply a blur filter on the text I rendered earleir to the CGImage.

Comment: @Teddy Aaron is right, the coordinate system in core graphics is flipped because in iOS the origin is top-left, on mac bottom-left and CG comes from osx. There are also come APIs in UIKit that create an already flipped CGContext.